# Huggingface transformers padding vs pad_to_max_length

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I'm running a code by using `pad_to_max_length = True` and everything works fine. Only I get a warning as follow:

> FutureWarning: The `pad_to_max_length` argument is deprecated and
> will be removed in a future version, use `padding=True` or
> `padding='longest'` to pad to the longest sequence in the batch, or
> use `padding='max_length'` to pad to a max length. In this case, you
> can give a specific length with `max_length` (e.g. `max_length=45`) or
> leave max_length to None to pad to the maximal input size of the model
> (e.g. 512 for Bert).

But when I change `pad_to_max_length = True` to `padding='max_length'` I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [60] at entry 0 and [64] at entry 6
```

How can I change the code to the new version? Is there anything I got wrong with the warning documentation?

This is my encoder:

```
encoding = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(
    poem,
    add_special_tokens=True,
    max_length= 60,
    return_token_type_ids=False,
    pad_to_max_length = True,
    return_attention_mask=True,
    return_tensors='pt',
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the documentation is not complete enough!

You should add `truncation=True` too to memic the `pad_to_max_length = True`.

like this:

```
encoding = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(
    poem,
    add_special_tokens=True,
    max_length=self.max_len,
    return_token_type_ids=False,
    padding='max_length',
    truncation=True,
    return_attention_mask=True,
    return_tensors='pt',
)
```